# JObject/JToken doesnt Log on NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

I have a class and some of properties are dynamic, when my class is pass to some action API the method undestand as a JObject, the problem is to Log on NLOG, when I try to do that, my log from my properties Dynamic shows up "[]" example bellow:

```
myProperty:[

    [[]],
    [],
    []
]
```

When I try convert all over my class Objet to JObject(Newtonsoft) all my log will be [] like bellow:

```
{ "time": "2019-05-13 18:12:16.2224", "level": "DEBUG", "JsonProperties": { "log": [[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[[[]],[[]],[[]]]],[[[[[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]]]],[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[[[]],[[]],[[]]]],[[[[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]]]]],[[[[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]]]]],[[[[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]]]]]]]]]]]],[[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]]]]]]] }, "message": "Testando performance no LoggerGenerator.", "log": [[],[]] }
```

I solved this problem converts JObject to Dictionary and Works perfectly, the problem is overhead to do that.

I need to solve this problem without create my own method and converts to Dictionary

Thanks.

Comment: You are (in a poor fashion) showing some data, but not any of the real code with either case. You really need to show that code.

Comment: NLog 4.6.4 has been released: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.6.4 with additional support for navigating expando-like-objects like JSON.NET JObject (without doing ToString).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JObject` is an `IEnumerable` and NLog will try to enumerate it.

You can do the following:

```
logger.Info("Hello {0}", jObject); // No structured logging, becomes string.Format

logger.Info("Hello {$myobj}", jObject); // Structured logging that forces JObject.ToString

logger.Info("Hello {myobj}", jObject.ToString()); // Converts to string upfront
```

You can also customize how NLog handles special objects (Like JObject) by overriding these:

- NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.ValueFormatter
- NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.JsonConverter

Comment: NLog 4.6.4 has been released: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/4.6.4 with additional support for navigating expando-like-objects like JSON.NET JObject (without doing ToString).